# Hibernate one-to-one cascade-all don't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, one-to-one, cascade

'Dear masters, currently learning Spring+Hibernate. I added HibernateUtil class to use it after for creating/deleting etc commands. I used cascadeALL for one-to-one mapping and when i run delete or create classes, they update only Instructor table in db, not related Instuctor Detail table. It works, if i write commands like in CreateDemo class - session.save(tempInstructor);
session.save(tempInstructorDetail); but as i understand i should be able to write only session.save(tempInstructor); - and this would update also linked table. The same for DeleteDemo. Why cascade = CascadeType.ALL does not work?'

```
enter code here
      

@Entity
@Table(name = "instructor")
public class Instructor {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column( name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "instructor_detail_id")
private InstructorDetail instructorDetail;
enter code here





@Entity
@Table(name = "instructor_detail")
public class InstructorDetail {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "youtube_channel")
private String youtubeChannel;

@Column(name = "hobby")
private String hobby;

enter code here



@SpringBootApplication
public class CreateDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CreateDemo.class, args);

   Instructor tempInstructor = new Instructor('Vilma', 'Kalna', 'vilma@gamil.com');
   InstructorDetail tempInstructorDetail = new InstructorDetail('www.vilma- 
teaching.com/youtube', 'teaching');

    try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {

        session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println('Saving instructor: ' + tempInstructor);
        //this will also save the details object
        //because of CascadeType.ALL
        session.save(tempInstructor);
        session.save(tempInstructorDetail);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}

enter code here



public class DeleteDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {

        session.beginTransaction();

        int theId = 2;
        Instructor tempInstructor = session.get(Instructor.class, theId);

        System.out.println('Found instructor: ' + tempInstructor);

        if(tempInstructor != null){
            System.out.println('Deleting: ' + tempInstructor);
            //will also delete associated details obj (Cascade)
            session.delete(tempInstructor);
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
enter code here

public class HibernateUtil {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

            // Hibernate settings equivalent to hibernate.cfg.xml's properties

            Properties settings = new Properties();
            settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, '');
            settings.put(Environment.URL, '');
            settings.put(Environment.USER, '');
            settings.put(Environment.PASS, '');
            settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, 'org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect');
            settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, 'true');
            settings.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, 'thread');

            configuration.setProperties(settings);

            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Instructor.class);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(InstructorDetail.class);

            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return sessionFactory;
enter code here
```

Comment: Where do you set `instructor.instructorDetail` field? It doesn't seem like you do this, so there's nothing to cascade to.

Comment: Thank you! I did not had and i needed tempInstructor.setInstructorDetail(tempInstructorDetail); before session.beginTransaction(); when running methods. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

While creating the entities there should be Bi-directional mapping. Create the below attribute in instructor detail and create getters and setters for it.

```
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "instructor_id")
    private Instructor instructor;
```

Create the below function inside the instructor detail entity

```
public void add(Instructor instructor) {
       this.instructor = instructor;
       instructor.setInstructorDetail(this)
    }
```

While creating the instructor call the above function using instructor detail object that is related to instructor object like,

```
instructorDetail.add(instructor);
```

Comment: I already have cascade, i don't need it from other side as well. I had one code part missing in my work, and adding this it works now. But seems im not allowed to answer to my own question, it gets deleted, so just making info that this is wrong - cascading only from one side!

Answer (score 0):

The InstructorDetail class also needs to do cascading because it should be bi-direction.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "instructor_id")
private Instructor instructor;
```

And create setter and getter for the instructor. I hope this will work

Comment: This isn't correct, you don't need cascades from the other side.